# How to transfer my apps, home, and OS X setup from an external Lion disk to an internal Mountain Lion SSD

Tags: macos

I installed an SSD (Samsung 830) as the internal drive of a Mid 2009 MacBook Pro, then attempted several times to clone the (now external) bootable OS X Lion drive using either SuperDuper or Carbon Copy Cloner to this new SSD. All attempts failed with disk writes failures (I tried two different SSDs with the same result: write failures). So installed Lion onto the new SSD using the OS X DVD installer and all went fine; then upgraded from Lion to Mountain Lion from the App Store. Again, all went great.

Which folders should I copy from the external Lion disk to the internal Mountain Lion SSD to get back all my apps, the MySQL server, PostgreSQL, ImageMagick, XCode installation, etc.? I would like to make the new Mountain Lion SSD contain all my useful apps so that I don’t have to reinstall from scratch.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to use **Migration Assistant**, which you can find in **`/Applications/Utilities/`**.

It can copy your apps, data and settings from your old disk if it's connected via USB, Firewire or Thunderbolt. You should end up with a mirror image of your old set up.

Start Migration Assistant, select *From another Mac, PC, Time Machine backup, or other disk* on the first screen, and *From a Time Machine backup or other disk* on the second screen, then follow the prompts.

If you need more detailed instructions, consult [Apple's Migration Assistant Guide](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4889) (you want the *Time Machine or other disk migration* section).